# How to add more than one image in the tabstrip (Kendo TabStrip)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tabstrip

Can anyone tell me if there's any way of adding more than one image in the Kendo tabStrip?

(I do not want to add sprite, but two different images whose click event can be accessed differently.)

Answer (score 1):

In the li element defining your tab header you can insert html content.

So you can do something like:

```
<div id="tabstrip">
     <ul>
         <li class="k-state-active">
           Text<span class="rainy">Your first image</span><spanclass="sunny">Your second image/span>
         </li>
     </ul>

......
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/eWuju